# Variables in Grunt.js

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, wildcard

Is it possible to access in grunt.js to variables of Wildcards outside of wildcards?
For example my config looks like that:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
globalConfig: grunt.file.readJSON('src/config.json'),
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
concat: {
  options: {
    separator: ';'
  },
  dist: {
    src: ['src/**/*.js'],
    dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
  }
},
uglify: {
  options: {
    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
  },
  dist: {
    files: {
      'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
    }
  }
},
qunit: {
  files: ['test/**/*.html']
},
jshint: {
  files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
  options: {
    // options here to override JSHint defaults
    globals: {
      jQuery: true,
      console: true,
      module: true,
      document: true
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
  tasks: ['jshint', 'qunit']
}
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint', 'qunit']);

grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'qunit', 'concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

My JSON-file ot globalConfig looks like that:

```
{
    "buildOrder": ["file1.js", "file2.js", "file3.js"]
}
```

How can I access to the buildOrder-Array and use it in concat.dist.src for example?

By wildcard I would access like that:

```
<%= globalConfig.buildOrder %>
```

But I want to use the array outside of the wildcard because it´s an array:

```
dist: {
    src: globalConfig.buildOrder,
    dest: 'dist/app.bundle.js'
}
```

Comment: Does `<% globalConfig.buildOrder %>` not work then?

Comment: I tried src: '<% globalConfig.buildOrder %>' but I only get the Warning: "Warning: must provide pattern Use --force to continue." I think it doesn´t work because globalConfig.buildOrder is an array.